# Transferring a new folder to remote using rsync?

Tags: rsync

If I create a completely new folder locally, I want to be able to rsync it remotely to an SFTP server, how can I achieve this?

I have tried:

rsync Documents/SomeFolder username@host:/home/Documents/RemoteFolder

Meaning SomeFolder must go into RemoteFolder, but this doesn't work, instead it creates a file called SomeFolder

Would appreciate some help on this

Comment: `rsync` does not work on top of SFTP. Probably, you actually want to talk to a SSH server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the -r (recurse into directories) option that should make it work.  Also -d (transfer directories without recursing) will work.  You should use -r if sometimes the folder will not be empty and you want to copy its contents.  Use either as shown here:

```
rsync -r Documents/SomeFolder username@host:/home/Documents/RemoteFolder
```